# Unable to set a random enum to a field

Tags: java, class, random, enumerated-types

```
public class Player {

    public String name;
    public boolean active;
    public boolean seeker;
    public Location randLocation;

    public Player(String name, boolean seeker) {
        this.name = name;
        this.seeker = seeker;
        //this.active= true;
        //this.randLocation=randLocation;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public boolean isSeeker() {
        return seeker;
    }

    public Location getrandLocation() {
        Random random = new Random();
        randLocation = (Location.values()[random.nextInt(Location.values().length)]);
        System.out.println(randLocation);
        return randLocation;
    }

    public void setRandLocation(Location randLocation) {
        this.randLocation = randLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [name=" + name + ", active=" + active + ", seeker=" + seeker + ", randLocation=" + randLocation
                + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player p1 = new Player("p1", false);
        System.out.println(p1);
    }
}
```

where Location is an enumerated set of locations like {BEDROOM, GARDEN, KITCHEN}.etc. When I create a player, and then print out the player, randLocation is always null, i've tried altering the constructer but still no avail. Any help would be useful!
Thank you.

Comment: You aren't setting `randLocation` anywhere. I think your intention is to do `this.randLocation = getrandLocation()`

Comment: Your ctor should call `getrandLocation()`. Although it seems odd that that function should create a new location instead of just returning `randLocation`. Maybe have a different function for this this: `public void randomizeLocation() {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following line in your constructor:

```
this.randLocation=getrandLocation();
```